# MongoDB get all the documents from hierarchy model

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently we have the collection structure as like below

```
db.testcol.insert({"name":"root_node","ip":"10.10","addr":"123 Node12"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"first_level_1","ip":"10.10","addr":"123 Node12","parent_name":"root_node"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"second_level","ip":"10.10","addr":"123 Node12","parent_name":"first_level_1"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"first_level_2","ip":"10.11","addr":"13 Node123","parent_name":"root_node"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"second_level_1","ip":"10.11","addr":"13 Node123","parent_name":"first_level_2"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"third_level_l","ip":"10.11","addr":"13 Node123","parent_name":"second_level_1"});
db.testcol.insert({"name":"third_level_2","ip":"10.11","addr":"13 Node123","parent_name":"second_level_1"});
```

Now I'll pass the root node in from front end ,I've to display level1,level2...level n documents . Please let me know how can do this.

In this sample document i'll search with "root_node" .It should display I've to display first_level,second_level and third_level documents . Parent_name is the relation key.

```
Edit:  Expected Output:  Input is "root_node" 

-- First level children for "root_node"

       /* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd252685"),
        "name" : "first_level_1",
        "ip" : "10.10",
        "addr" : "123 Node12",
        "parent_name" : "root_node"
    }

    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd252687"),
        "name" : "first_level_2",
        "ip" : "10.11",
        "addr" : "13 Node123",
        "parent_name" : "root_node"
    }

   -- Second level documents -- parent is  second_level1 and second_leve2
    /* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd252686"),
        "name" : "second_level",
        "ip" : "10.10",
        "addr" : "123 Node12",
        "parent_name" : "first_level_1"
    }

    /* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd252688"),
        "name" : "second_level_1",
        "ip" : "10.11",
        "addr" : "13 Node123",
        "parent_name" : "first_level_2"
    }

    /* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd252689"),
        "name" : "third_level_l",
        "ip" : "10.11",
        "addr" : "13 Node123",
        "parent_name" : "second_level_1"
    }

    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56654b5b1160f16ccd25268a"),
        "name" : "third_level_2",
        "ip" : "10.11",
        "addr" : "13 Node123",
        "parent_name" : "second_level_1"
    }
```

Comment: possibly db.testcol.find({parent_name:  $in: ["root_node", "first_level", "second_level"]}

Comment: I know only the root node name.Child and grandchild details should be fetched from parent document. In that case i cannot go with in operator with hard code values. The names will vary .

Comment: Anyway to go with aggregation framework?

Comment: @Root can you please add expected output to question?

Comment: @vishwas: I have edited my main question to include my expected output.